# Naming a subclass to store requirements of the parent class

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, naming-conventions

I have the class Party and inside i have some restrictions to join that party.

Looking like this:

```
class Party {
    String id;
    String name;
    Instant date;
    Requirement requirement;
}

class Requirement {
    int age;
    String dressCode;
    boolean drinkIncluded;
    ....
}
```

My question is: How should i name the subclass `Requirement`? I came up with three options but i cannot tell what is the best naming convention.

1. Requirements (in plural)
2. Requirement (in singular)
3. Requirements_configuration

Is there some design pattern that i am missing to solve this or i just can name it in plural in this scenario?

Comment: Why do you need a separate class for requirements rather than storing them directly in the Party class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perfectly acceptable to have plurals.

Requirements is not a subclass but here an embedded type. Requirements "is not" a party(inheritance). A party "has" requirements (composition).

Answer (score 1):

Requirement is not a subclass, since you are not inheriting it from the superclass Party. I would name it Requirements, as there is not one requirement but many more because you have four variables.

kind regards

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

In my view, you should use singular name as there is no collection of them.
What I mean is to pluralize when you have collection of requirements:

```
class Party {
    String id;
    String name;
    Instant date;
    Array<Requirement> requirements; // 's' is to indicate that it 
        // is a collection of requirements
}
```

However, class should have singular name:

```
class Requirement {
    // ... the code is omitted for the brevity
    String dressCode; // this is just property which describes requirement
}
```

We can look at simple example with `Person`:

```
class Person {
    String id;
    String name;    
}
```

and it is not really cool when we pluralize name:

```
class Persons {
    String id;
    String name;    
}
```

Read more about [сlasses naming: singular or plural](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/103720/classes-naming-singular-or-plural#:%7E:text=Definitely%20singular.,a%20namespace%20than%20anything%20else.)

Comment: I also thought about this approach but then if want to access to the requirement dressCode it is more complex than just doing .GetRequirements().getDressCode()

Comment: @StepUp does't work with your example. GetRequirements() is an array.  And here he will have in the end an array with just a single element

Comment: @CodeScale ooops, it is small typo. I've edited my comment

Comment: @Paplusc  in my view, it is okay: `GetRequirement().getDressCode()`. Isn't?